# RSpec with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

im new to rails :)
im trying to run my first test. why does this test pass? username should have at least 2 characters, my username has more and it still passes test.

user.rb:

```
validates :username, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
```

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

before do
  @user = User.new(username: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                   password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end

describe "when name is not present" do
  before { @user.username="aaaahfghg" }
  it { should_not be_valid }   end

end
```

Comment: i dont see the test for username length. also the validation is for a MINIMUM of 2 anything more than 2 will pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "when name is not present" do
 before {  @user.username = "aaaahfghg" }
 it { should_not be_valid }   
end
```

First, your describe block is testing for the wrong thing. If you would like to test for "name is not present" you should set:

> @user.username = "" #makes the username empty.

However, in order to check if the username is empty you should add `validates :username, presence: true` . Although you might not need it since you have a `{ minimum: 2 }` validation

Now, `@user.username = "aaaahf"` # a better way of writing it is 'a' * 5 for example, it create a string of 5 a's = aaaaa.

That says that your username is more than 2 characters so your validation is fine, `{ minimum: 2 }` the test should pass.

If you want to make sure that usernames are more than 2 characters then

```
@user.username = 'a'
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
it { should_not be_valid }
```

Uses the [implicit subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/implicit-subject). RSpec automatically creates an instance of the class `User` that you can then use implicitly within an `it` block. But your test then creates another instance and assigns it to `@user` -- the two instances are not the same.

If you want to use the implicit subject, you can do:

```
subject { User.new(args) }
before {  subject.username = "aaaahfghg" }
it { should_not be_valid }
```