# devise rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

why this test does not pass? i use devise for authentication.

user.rb

```
  validates :username, presence: true, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
```

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(username: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  describe "name" do
    before { @user.username="test" }
    it { should be_valid }
  end

end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSpec with devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209197/rspec-with-devise)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a subject to call 'it' in RSpec. For example, you can add

subject { @user }

after your 'before do' block.

In the future, be sure to copy the error message as well so that everyone knows where to look!